# Duplicate tasks are being displayed even though only one document is being added to firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I'm using react-redux-firebase to create a task manager. When a task is created, a user fills out a form and this data is used to add a document to my todo collection in firebase. So we have a document for each todo. Another component then maps each document in the todo collection to a card so the user can see each todo

The problem comes in when we create the task, it displays a duplicate task under our to-do section. However only one new document is added to our todo collection in firebase. Also, once I refresh the page, the duplicate task disappears. I'm completely confused as to why a duplicate task is displayed even though only one new document is created in firebase. What would cause the duplicate to be there to begin with? Any help will be much appreciated!

Hopefully these two images help you understand the problem a little better as I found it a little challenging to explain.

Example of the duplicate:

[image]

when I refresh the page, the duplicate disappears:

[image]

This is the function that submits the form to firebase:

```
handleCreateSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
const { firestore } = this.props;
this.props.users.forEach(user => {
  if (user.uid === this.props.auth.uid) {
    const dueDate = new Date(this.state.due + " " + this.state.eta);
    const newTask = {
      title: this.state.title,
      description: this.state.description,
      due: dueDate,
      createdBy: user.name,
      status: "todo",
      department: this.state.departmentName
    };

    firestore
      .add({ collection: "todo" }, newTask)
      .then(() => console.log("task added"))
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("error");
      });
    this.setState({
      title: "",
      description: "",
      due: "",
      eta: ""
    });
    this.addCreateNotification(user.name);
   } else if (!user.uid === this.props.auth.uid) {
    return null;
  }
  });
  this.handleCreateClose();
 };
```

And this is the function that maps to each document to a card:

```
ren = () => {
if (this.props.todo) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.props.todo.map((item, i) => {
        if (item.department === this.props.match.params.id) {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <div className="card" style={{ backgroundColor: "#d71636" 
  }}>
                <div className="card-content white-text">
                  <span className="card-title">
                    {item.title}{" "}
                    <Start
                      id={item.id}
                      className="start"
                      style={{ float: "right" }}
                      onClick={e => {
                        this.handleClickOpen(e);
                      }}
                    />
                    <Delete
                      id={item.id}
                      className="start"
                      style={{ float: "right" }}
                      onClick={e => {
                        this.delete(e);
                      }}
                    />
                  </span>
                  <p>
                    <b>Created By: </b>
                    {item.createdBy}
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <b>Due:</b> {moment(item.due.toDate()).calendar()}
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <b>Description: </b>
                    {item.description}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
} else {
  return <Loading />;
}
};
```